# Strange warning when using #define XX __pragma

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings, preprocessor, deprecation-warning

I'm using the following preprocessor definitions to disable specific warnings for different c++ compilers.

Here's the code

```cpp
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_PUSH __pragma(warning(push))
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_POP __pragma(warning(pop))
  #define DISABLE_WARNING(warningNumber) __pragma(warning(disable : (warningNumber)))
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_DEPRECATED_FUNCTION DISABLE_WARNING(4996)

#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
  #define DO_PRAGMA(X) _Pragma(#X)
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_PUSH DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic push)
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_POP DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic pop)
  #define DISABLE_WARNING(warningName) DO_PRAGMA(GCC diagnostic ignored #warningName)

  #define DISABLE_WARNING_DEPRECATED_FUNCTION DISABLE_WARNING(-Wdeprecated-declarations)
#else
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_PUSH
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_POP
  #define DISABLE_WARNING_DEPRECATED_FUNCTION
#endif
```

These defines works for GCC and CLANG but not for MSVC compiler.
On MSVC compiler I get the following warning:

> (23): warning C4081: expected ')'; found '('

You can see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/hTErEbG7W

How can I fix this warning for MSVC compiler?

Comment: Looks like MSVC's warning pragma [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170) doesn't take the innermost parentheses. That is, it should look like `__pragma(warning(disable: 4996))`, not `__pragma(warning(disable: (4996)))`

Comment: I found the solution here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/08/30/how-to-disable-a-warning-in-cpp/
I thought I can use this out of the box. But even when I remove the parentheses, I got the same result: https://godbolt.org/z/PWaG99daz

Comment: Oh wait. It woks.
Great help. Thank you :)

Comment: The version you link to doesn't have those extra parentheses around `warningNumber` either.